Export and visual customization features in angular High-chart
I am new to HighChart and currently exploring HighChart capabilities. I am looking forward to integrate HighChart in my angular application.
I have below queries, I tried to find the answers in Highchart FAQ/documentations but dint find much information.
Question 1: Can we export the entire data what we are binding to HighChart using the Highchart library itself, instead of writing separate own functionality?
Question 2: Can we allow end user to customize the HighChart visuals, it could be convert line chart to pie chart OR change the x-axis / y-axis field etc.? <Something similar what Power BI has - link
Thank you in advance.


Yes, you can do that by including the exporting and export-data modules, which allow the users to extract data into a CSV, XLS or a HTML table: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv
Of course, there are multiple ways to allow end-users to change type or appearance of the chart. For example, you can create a method that programatically toggles between a line and column chart. You can also check out the Highcharts Editor v2, which is an enriched chart editor: https://lab.highsoft.com/editorv2/

Example code snippet:
let isColumn = false;

chart.update({
    chart: {
        type: isColumn ? 'line' : 'column'
    }
});
isColumn = !isColumn; // update boolean flag

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/931yhrpn/
API:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type
